# Bad display select field options on iPhone 11 / iOS 16.2

Tags: ios, iphone, bootstrap-4, ios16, iphone11

Select options are displayed incorrectly on iPhone 11 / iOS 16.2
Icon "check" is overlapped by option value:

[image: Image select options with bug]

HTML code:

```
<div class="form-group d-inline-flex mb-0 form-group-quantity">
    <label for="quantity_wanted">Qty</label>
    <select class="custom-select custom-select-sm" name="product-quantity" id="quantity_wanted" data-product-id="27" value="1">
        <option value="1" selected="">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="7">7</option>
        <option value="8">8</option>
        <option value="9">9</option>
        <option value="10">10</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

I'm using Bootstrap v4.6.0. Tested on few devices, only on iPhone 11 the bug is reproducing.
Does anybody know why this issue happens?

Default iPhone's select comportment is expected:

[image: Image select options without bug]